# PHP mail() headers not working with certain "from" email adresses

Tags: php, email

Didn't find the exact answer for my question. The problem is, the code sends an email (user to user), so I did a $headers for a reply-to with the email entered by the user. In this $headers, I put the "From" email as the email of our website. However, the email does not get sent. It does send appropriately when I put a Gmail or Hotmail in the "from" position. So the problem appears to be our website email. Should I talk to my host or could there be something else? Just ask if there needs to be more details.

Comment: Please, give an example of your code.

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: If you are sure all the email addresses you tested are well-formed and some of them work and others do not work then you better ask the technical support of your website hosting company. They can find the real reason in the log files and, most probably, either fix the problem (if any) or guide you about the way to send the email to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to talk with your host for your website email address is working or not.
Please check mail in spam when send using you website email address

Comment: Don't worry for the spam, I check this folder a lot! I will get in touch with my host company. Thank you for your time!